# Javascript RegEx find one out of several

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

I am trying to replace a the country code from a telefone number. As I do not know how the user entered the telefone number I am trying to get one out of several with a reg expression.

In a first step I removed a possible '+' and brackets as well as spaces.

Here is my try, which does not work:

```
result = "4901762887541";
result.replace(/^00490|^0049|^490|^49/g, '0');
```

What would be the correct way to find the different country codes?

Comment: Are you certain it doesn't work? I tried it here with some sample data and added `m`, and it seems to work fine. http://regex101.com/r/vK2kQ5/1#javascript

Comment: On what text does it "not work"? Have you considered `/^(00490|0049)..` etc., or the much simpler `/^0?0?490?/`?

Comment: what is the value of `result`?

Comment: @Jongware: can you post
    replace(/^0?0?490?/g, '0');
 because that works :)

Comment: I'd be happy to but I'm not quite convinced your own code "does not work" -- what @Bifrost says.

Comment: I tested my code in the console with: 
result = "4901762887541";
console.log(result.replace(/^00490|^0049|^490|^49/g, '0'));
 and this time it works. It seems I had an error in a different place. Thanks @Jongware

Comment: `/^[0]{0,2}49[0]{0,1}/g` or `/^0{0,2}490{0,1}/g` are other ways to write your Regex without the use of or's